# Read hashmap nested properties dynamically

Tags: java

I have the JSON below:

```
"total":"2",
"offset":"1",
"limit":"2",
"results":[{    
    "code":1,
    "title":"RESTAURANTE SADOCHE",
    "contact":{
        "code":10,
        "name":"HENRIQUE BARBALHO",
        "company":{
            "code":100,
            "name":"RESTAURANTE SADOCHE LTDA-ME"
        }
    }
},
{
    "code":2,
    "title":"ARNALDO GRILL",
    "contact":{
        "code":20,
        "name":"FÁTIMA COSTA",
        "company":{
            "code":200,
            "name":"COSTA NATAL RESTAURANTE EIRELI"
        }
    }
}]
```

I turned this JSON into a Java HashMap using the Gson library.

```
Map<String, Object> retMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonUpString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

I need to dynamically read some properties of this created hashmap. Ex: title, name of contact and name of company.

Sometimes these properties (title, name of contact and name of company) can be inside lists.

Below my code:

```
String propertyName = "name";
String nesting = "results;contact;company";
String[] levels = nesting.split(";");

Map map = new HashMap();
map = retMap;

for (int i = 0; i < niveis.length; i++) {                        
    map = (Map)map.get(levels[i]);        
    System.out.println(map);

    if (i == levels.length - 1) {
        System.out.println(map.get(propertyName));
    }
}
```

But if the properties (results, contact or company) return more than one object, the JSON returns them as lists, and I can't get the information I need.

Comment: Sure, but you'll need to tell us exactly what you need help with. [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I'm sorry dnault, I inserted more information about my problem, and the implementation that I managed to do, it should already serve as a basis for understanding what I need.

Comment: Please include some explanation about the expected output. I get that you want to read single objects, but also multiple objects sometimes. But what is the expected result type?

Comment: did you mean that you get HashMap only if  JSON contains one object?

Comment: No, I get a JSON from an API and I transform this JSON into a HashMap through the Gson library. This JSON can have any structure. Ex: its properties can be string, date, int, etc ..., can be other objects and can also be lists of objects. The method I created can read the properties if they are string, date, int, etc ... and also when they are objects; but when I have lists of objects, no. I need a method that is generic enough to read all properties regardless of type and level of nesting

Comment: I solved the problem using org.json.simple.JSONObject class, I inserted the solution in a below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using...

```
private static void leJSON(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
        Set < String > ks = ((JSONObject) object).keySet();
        for (String key: ks) {
            Object value = ((JSONObject) object).get(key);
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.printf("%s=%s (%s)\n", key, value, value.getClass().getSimpleName());
                if (value.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("JSONArray")) {
                    JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) value;
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++) {
                        leJSON(ja.get(i));
                    }
                }
                if (value.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("JSONObject")) {
                    leJSON(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main method...

```
String json = "{...}";
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonString2);        
readJSON(object);
```